# How to read the Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having a difficult time understanding the Rails API. I am trying to figure out a way to understand what I can call from certain points inside Rails, such as when I'm in a controller, so I wrote something to tell me all the methods that are available sorted by what Module/Class they fall under:

```
last_sig = ""
self.methods.each do |method|
    #i_am = self.method(method).owner
    #puts i_am.class
    #places.push(self.method(method).owner)
    m = self.method(method)
    sig = "#{m.owner.class}: #{m.owner}"
    if sig != last_sig
        last_sig = sig
        puts sig
    end
    puts "    #{method}"
end
```

As an example, I find out (just using this as an easy example) that I can use the render() method and it is located at ActionController::Instrumentation, so then I look at the render() function there and it says:

```
render(*args)
# File actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb, line 38
def render(*args)
  render_output = nil
  self.view_runtime = cleanup_view_runtime do
    Benchmark.ms { render_output = super }
  end
  render_output
end
```

That is all is says, I don't understand how from this I could understand how it works, then I do some more searching and by "luck" I discover that it is documented in ActionView, and I wonder how I was able to know this? Anyway, any tips on how to read the API would be appreciated- It seems like many of the things in the API are not documented for a User, and I don't know if they are for the User or for the developers of Rails- I'm used to using a documentation like jQuery which seems much easier to Discover functionality by using-

Comment: See that `super` call? It's a hint for you. Actual rendering happens somewhere up the inheritance chain.

Comment: Also `self.class.ancestors` might help. This gives you a bunch of classes/modules which are included in the current class. You can lookup their documentation at the usual places then.